# Problemas al compilar en C++

Tags: c++, c++11

hola estoy recien aprendiendo algo de C++ y me descargue CLion de Jetbrain antes instale el mingw siguiendo un video, la razon es que estaba siguiendo el cursoy al tratar de compilar o ejecutar me tira un error que no se muy bien que me indica parece que me dice que hay dos main pero no se como solucionarlo y salir de la duda aquí dejo la imagen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estás definiendo la función `main` en 2 archivos diferentes (`HolaMundo.cpp` y `TiposDatosBasicos.cpp`).

Sólo puede haber 1 función `main` por proyecto.

Lo que puedes hacer es cambiarles el nombre a esas funciones y llamarlas desde el `main` en otro archivo.

```
// HolaMundo.cpp
int holaMundo() {
  cout<<"Hola mundo"<<endl;
  return 0;
}

// TiposDatosBasicos.cpp
int tiposBasicos() {
  int numero = 15;
  cout<<numero;
  return 0;
}

// Main.cpp
int main() {
  holaMundo();
  tiposBasicos();
}
```

Comment: entiendo pense que el main era como en java cuando usas es mi error gracias